# open source video sound extractor

Tags: audio, extract

I wanna an open source library to extract audio from video file through program code.

Comment: please describe your question more precisely.

Comment: Please specify OS and other helpful details.

Answer (score 2):

GStreamer and FFMPEG are the popular choices. I only have experience on the latter and based on that I would recommend the former.

Answer (score 1):

The first page of Google results includes links both to ffmpeg, and to Wikipedia's comprehensive list of open-source video editing software.